# Trying to use Cons function in Purescript

Tags: purescript

Heres my code:

```
print 1: [2,3]
```

When I run it I get

```
  Cannot unify type
    Data.List.List
  with type
    Prim.Array
```

Whats going on?

Answer (score 7):

`[2, 3]` has type `Array Int`. `(:)` has type `a -> List a -> List a` in `Data.List`. You need to convert to a `List`. Also, what you have will parse as

```
(print 1) : [2, 3]
```

I think you want

```
print (1 : toList [2, 3])
```

or

```
print $ 1 : toList [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

In psci, look at the type of (:)

```
> :t (:)
forall a. a -> Data.List.List a -> Data.List.List a
```

and the type of [2, 3]

```
> :t [2, 3]
Prim.Array Prim.Int
```

You can see that the (:) function expects 2 values: a value, and a List of the same type. In your question, you gave it an Array of Ints. You can use the Data.List.toList function to get the type that (:) expects

```
> import Data.List
> show $ 1 : (toList [1, 2])
"Cons (1) (Cons (1) (Cons (2) (Nil)))"
```